# "This project is incompatible..." after VS 2013 Update 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

After installing Update 4 for VS 2013, I immediately started getting the message

**This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio**

when I try to open all my MVC projects.

- I've tried following advice on older posts, such as changing the version of visual studio, and checking for other updates, but none have worked.
- I am using Visual Studio Premium 2013 and have .Net 4.5.  It happens to projects that target both 4.0 and 4.5.
- This is happening with MVC projects, but it does not happen when opening a simple project containing only .cs files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repairing Visual Studio turned out to be the solution.

I believe the initial update was unsuccessful because the C drive was low on space.  Clearing up space, and repairing both .Net 4.5.1 and Visual Studio did the trick.